# Using date(sec_to_timestamp()) for a certain date range

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a query like this.

```
SELECT
  some_column
FROM
  [some_table]
WHERE DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) IN ('2017-09-10','2017-09-11')
```

(the *timestamp* column contains timestamp in seconds, integer column).

Is there another way to extract data for certain date range without using the "IN" operator?

I tried using REGEXP_MATCH(), but I guess that is certainly not an option.

May by there's even a better way for extracting date from a column containing timestamp in seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead of legacy SQL, you can make use of the proper `DATE` type. For your filter, you can use a `BETWEEN` expression such as:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  some_column
FROM
  `some_table`
WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) BETWEEN
    '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-11'
```